# Getting an access violation when trying to write

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I have been following a tutorial on making a 2d game in C++ when all of a sudden I got an error. It worked in the tutorial with all of the same code so it could be something wrong with my setup but I didn't think it would be.

I am using SFML and here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "Test Game", Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);
    Event ev;

    // Game Loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // Event Polling
        while (window.pollEvent(ev)) {
            switch (ev.type) {
            case Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;

            case Event::KeyPressed:
                if (ev.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
                    window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Update

        // Render
        window.clear();

        // Draw New Content

        // Tell app that window is done drawing
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00E62B0A in 2D game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000065.

Comment: Likely you have a null pointer.

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash and locate where in your code it happens, and examine the values of all involved variables at that location when the crash happens.

Comment: Memory location `0x00000065` is so small, it is typically indicative of code that is trying to write to some offset `0x65` bytes from a pointer.  And in your code, the pointer is `0x00000000`, or "null".

Comment: If this is your entire code my advice is to make sure you have the correct binaries for your  compiler. If you are using mingw make sure you are using mingw binaries. Also if you are using msvc make sure that you are not using Release libraries in the Debug configuration or Debug libraries in the Release configuration.

Comment: For a problem like this, using your [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will be several orders of magnitude faster than trying to debug the problem through Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sadly, it may work in the tutorial with the exact same code. The presenter of the tutorial may simply be experiencing a different outcome of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and not realizing they have a mistake.